Irreducible representations on commutative real $C^*$-algebra
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a (complex) commutative $C^*$-algebra and $\mathcal{H}$ be a (complex) Hilbert space. If $\pi : \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B(H)}$ is an irreducible representation, then we know $dim(\mathcal{H})=1$.
The same is not true if we work in the real case. i.e, if $\mathcal{A}$ is a commutative real $C^*$-algebra and $\mathcal{H}$ is a real Hilbert space, then it is not necessarily true that if $\pi : \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B(H)}$ is an irreducible representation, then $dim(\mathcal{H})=1$. For eg: consider the representation of $\mathbb{C}$ on $M_2(\mathbb{R})$
$z \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}Re(z) & Im(z) \\ -Im(z) & Re(z) \end{bmatrix}$.
I have two questions:

Is it true that $dim(\mathcal{H}) \leq 2$ ?
If $\mathcal{A} = C_{\mathbb{R}}(\Omega)$ (real valued continuous functions on a compact Hausdorff space $\Omega$), then $dim(\mathcal{H})=1$ ?

Thanks in advance!

I’m pretty sure both are true. For commutative real $C^\ast$-algebras, if I’m not mistaken, irreducible representations still correspond to maximal ideals. Quotienting out an maximal ideal results in a field extending $\mathbb{R}$, and there are only two such things, $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$. So any irreducible representation factors through either $\mathbb{R}$, in which case the representation is 1-d; or $\mathbb{C}$, in which case the representation is 2-d (since the only irreducible representation of $\mathbb{C}$ is the 2-d one you wrote down).

For $C_\mathbb{R}(\Omega)$, all of its maximal ideals are of the form the set of all functions that vanish at a given fixed point, and quotienting out such ideals always result in $\mathbb{R}$, so all its irreducible representations are 1-d.

Yes, it's either $1$ or $2$ depending on whether the endomorphism algebra is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04091.
